# Mössbauer effect - Deriving the recoil energy formula

Tags: nuclear-physics, photon-emission, gamma-rays

I am working on a problem that deals with the Mössbauer effect and calculating the recoil energy on a iron-57 atom, initially at rest and excited to 14.4 keV, after it emits a photon. In the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6ssbauer_effect), the author states that we can find the following:

$$ E_{recoil} = \frac{ {E_\mathrm\gamma}^2}{2Mc^2} $$

This provides me with the correct recoil energy which I then use to get back to velocity. However, I am not sure how this formula is derived using basic energy formulas. Can anyone explain how they got to this?

I believe I have to use the following somehow:

$$ E^2 - (pc)^2 = (mc^2)^2 $$

**EDIT:** I was confused by two major things: the momentum formula of the nucleus, and then using the two momentums (photon + nucleus)  to solve for Erecoil (which is kinetic energy).

Solve the Relativistic Energy formula for a massless object to get a momentum of:
$$p_{photon}= \frac{E_{\mathrm\gamma}}{c} $$

Then, I set this momentum equal to that of the nucleus (but divide by Mass because it is not massless):
$$v_{nucleus}= \frac{E_{\mathrm\gamma}}{Mc} $$

Then, I use the Kinetic Energy Formula:
$$K= \frac{1}{2}Mv^2 $$

Plug in the velocity of the nucleus:
$$K= \frac{{E_{\mathrm\gamma}}^2}{2Mc^2} $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relativistic equation for the energy of a particle is:

$$ E^2 = p^2c^2 + m^2c^4 $$

This applies to a photon but we have to set the rest mass $m$ to zero and this gives us:

$$ p = \frac{E_\gamma}{c} $$

From conservation of momentum the momentum of the nucleus must also be $p$ (in the opposite direction). Since the energies aren't high enough to require a relativistic treatment we can just use the equation for the momentum of the nucleus $p = Mv$, which gives us:

$$ v = \frac{E_\gamma}{Mc} $$

And finally the kinetic energy $E = \tfrac{1}{2}Mv^2$ giving us:

$$ E = \frac{E_\gamma^2}{2Mc^2} $$

Comment: Thank you! The part that I was getting confused by is the jump from the two momentum formulas to plugging it into the kinetic energy formula. I will solve it in my original post just to make sure I am thinking correctly!